# Dependencies cannot be found in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, path

I'm trying to set up a test environment for my node project in a docker container. I'm using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.4.0-alpine

RUN npm install -g ava

USER node
WORKDIR /home/node
COPY --chown=node package*.json ./
RUN npm install
ENV PATH=/home/node/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

WORKDIR /test

CMD [ "npm", "test" ]
```

I'm running the container with the following command:

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/test -t <name>
```

Right now I'm getting this error:

```
> goFit@1.0.0 test /test
> ava

(node:24) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not resolve required module ’esm’
    at /home/node/node_modules/ava/lib/api.js:27:10
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveModules (/home/node/node_modules/ava/lib/api.js:23:25)
    at new Api (/home/node/node_modules/ava/lib/api.js:48:26)
    at Object.exports.run (/home/node/node_modules/ava/lib/cli.js:386:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/node_modules/ava/cli.js:10:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:24) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:24) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

If I set up the `NODE_PATH` environment variable using:

```
ENV NODE_PATH=/home/node/node_modules
```

Then the error changes to:

```
  Uncaught exception in tests/workout_factory.test.js

  Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'ava' imported from /test/tests/workout_factory.test.js
  Did you mean to import ava/index.js?

  › Did you mean to import ava/index.js?
  › packageResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:620:9)
  › moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:659:14)
  › Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:752:11)
  › Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:97:40)
  › Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:242:28)
  › ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:50:40)
  › link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:49:36)
```

If it helps you, I'm using the following `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "goFit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "api web para entrenamiento personal",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "docs"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "ava"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/ElenaMerelo/goFit.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "workout",
    "fitness",
    "fit"
  ],
  "author": "Elena Merelo Molina",
  "license": "GPL-3.0",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/ElenaMerelo/goFit/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ElenaMerelo/goFit#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ava": "^3.13.0",
    "esm": "^3.2.25"
  },
  "ava": {
    "files": [
      "tests/**/*",
      "!tests/exercises_data.js"
    ],
    "cache": false,
    "require": [
      "esm"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Does anyone know why is not working?

Comment: It looks like nothing from your Dockerfile is actually getting used; why not just use a host Node process to run this test?

Comment: That's not the question, I need to use it that way and it should work with that configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are wrong with your Dockerfile:

1. You need to install *globally* all dev dependencies. They need to be available for all users
2. You need to set up a `/node_modules` directory with permissions at the top of your filesystems. Not a good thing, but it's at the same level as `/test`, which is where it will stop looking for. That leaves the `Dockerfile` in this shape

```
RUN npm install -g ava esm && mkdir /node_modules && chown node /node_modules && chmod 755 /node_modules

USER node
COPY --chown=node package*.json ./
RUN npm install
ENV PATH=/home/node/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

WORKDIR /test

CMD [ "npm", "test" ]
```

Please also remember

- Use `npm ci` in production environments. npm i should be used only for installing individual packages.
- `PATH` setting is probably not needed anyway.
- Delete `package*json` as `root` when you're done.